# Dynamic dropdown in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular, i am having requirement like create dynamically a dropdown  with 3 buttons(add,edit,delete) by clicking on a link(create drop down button). We can create a multiple dropdown by clicking on a link Add/delete button should show with dropdown by default. If click on add/delete should display edit and viceversa.

Comment: i see no question mark in your question. you have to much more specify what you want instead of explaining your tasks

Comment: Hi Eni, welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, we can't really see what your issue is. This isn't a tutorial request site, it is a problem resolution forum. If you have specific code examples of *what you have tried,* we can help.

Answer (score 0):

See angularjs directives https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

For dynamic handling of DOM directive is the best

You can also check https://angular-ui.github.io/ for more features make with directive